# CKEditor image path

Tags: php, symfony, ckeditor, elfinder

I using the IvoryCKEditorBundle in symfony with elfinder as filebrowser. The editor is in the subroute `/admin`, the images in `/images`. When I insert them with elfinder, they have the route `images\name.jpg`. two things are wrong. Frist: the `\` must be a `/` and second because the editor is in a subroute he can't display, `../images/name.jpg` would work. Is it possible to change the url or the routing of symfony, so that it displays in the admin area the image and also in the frontend, so the image url is `images/name.jpg`?

Comment: check the Elfinder configuration for the public path , try to use $_SERVER variables better than hard coding it yourself , or write a full path as i assume the admin folder is not at the same root the images folder is

Comment: I set `url: dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . '/../files/'` nothing helps.

Comment: Try to use HTTP://domain.com/folder/

Comment: You should be able to edit url in `getFileCallback` if you have some specific paths/setup